# Android application not working in 3G network,but works in WIFI

Tags: android, web-services, 3g

I am doing a Hebrew app and the app receives some data from the server.The app works perfectly on wifi network but when it is in 3G network there is no response from the server.

I checked the response in the inbuilt android browser and I am getting "502 error"(Bad Gateway). But the app works on another phone with the same 3g network.

My http request to server works in background,not in the UI thread.

Comment: Think your are connecting to the local server i guess because it will work on wifi and not in mobile 3g data

Comment: @kummand .Thanks for the reply.But the app works perfectly on another phone using 3g network..

Comment: My device is Samsung Galaxy S2 android 2.3.5 GINGER BREAD JHKG2

Comment: Doesn't sound like an android issue... sounds like a phone/provider issue.

Comment: Sounds like a potential difference in the HTTP headers sent out by your device causing a gateway in your carrier's network choking on it. My first guess is some language/Unicode-related header (Hebrew) that is not understood (or misunderstood) by a proxy in the carrier's network. One thing to try is to look at the HTTP headers sent out by your device by using a tool such as [Ping & DNS](http://www.ulfdittmer.com/android/) or Firebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the similar problem on Samsung S3 mini device.
Do you by any use case GSON library? I assume that this have something to do with it

Application is working on 4 other devices but fails only on S3mini!